# Flask Image choose a local image and display it on html

Tags: image, flask

I am running a **flask server locally**. I want to choose a local **file first and display it on the website**. Can I do this by **not** uploading it? If I can, how can I finish it? **Thanks**.

I just want to **choose a file** path using a file chooser and display it on HTML. But the solutions I get are all file **uploading**. Could you please help me with this?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this. [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)

Comment: How can I pass through a `local ressource not allowed` error?